# Where are the CentOS 6.4 documents?

Tags: centos, documentation

I'm only able to find up to version 5 on CentOS.com:

http://www.centos.org/docs/

Even though CentOS 6 was released back in mid-2011..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been using the RHEL6 docs instead. They're essentially the same.

- https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/

Here are the [CentOS 6 Release Notes](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.0?highlight=%28%28Manuals%7CReleaseNotes%7CCentOS6.0%29%29), if you're interested. The highlight the above link there as well.