# Where can I find Centos 7 documentation?

Tags: centos, documentation

Where can I find CentOS 7 documentation like this one?

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/index.html

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

I see only till CentOS 5
https://www.centos.org/docs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the CentOS 6.4 documents?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101868/where-are-the-centos-6-4-documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with the release notes:

https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7

which (in **12. Further Reading**) points you to

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/

as well as the CentOS wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, RedHat's documentation is supposed to cover CentOS.

For comparison of both see: [Is CentOS exactly the same as RHEL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/is-centos-exactly-the-same-as-rhel#27330)